# What is the best, most accurate timer in C++?

Tags: c++, timer

What is the best, most accurate timer in C++?

Comment: The absolute best timer would probably be some system-specific call on a RTOS running on some embedded device attached to an atomic clock.  Is that what you're looking for, or are you willing to settle for something a little less than "the best, most accurate timer"?

Comment: @James And the time taken to travel along the wires, and to be processed/etc is also taken into approximate consideration? (That sentence didn't make any sense...)

Comment: Also, such a high resolution timer might eat CPU.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer to this is platform-specific. The operating system is responsible for keeping track of timing and consequently, the C++ language itself provides no language constructs or built-in functions for doing this.

However, here are some resources for platform-dependent timers:

- **Windows API** - `SetTimer`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx
- **Unix** - `setitimer`: http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer

A cross-platform solution might be [boost::asio::deadline_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html).

Comment: Answer relevant for not ridiculously time based critical applications

Answer (score 14):

In C++11 you can portably get to the highest resolution timer with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "chrono_io"

int main()
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
    auto t1 = Clock::now();
    auto t2 = Clock::now();
    std::cout << t2-t1 << '\n';
}
```

Example output:

```
74 nanoseconds
```

"chrono_io" is an extension to ease I/O issues with these new types and is freely available [here](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/duration_io/chrono_io.html).

There is also an implementation of `<chrono>` available in boost (might still be on tip-of-trunk, not sure it has been released).

Comment: I tried running the now() function for 300 million times and there are around 100 times that the latency/difference of t1 and t2 are larger than 10 microseconds. Is it because of context switching or something else? Thanks

Comment: @user1687035:  Context switching is a likely culprit.  It depends on what platform, which compiler (even compiler version), what other processes are on the machine, etc.  A general purpose computer is not a great clock, unless it is constantly asking other computers what time it is. ;-)  On macOS I get fairly solid timings *unless* time machine is backing up, spotlight is indexing, or mail is fetching.

Answer (score 2):

Under windows it would be `QueryPerformanceCounter`, though seeing as you didn't specify any conditions it possible to have an external ultra high resolution timer that has a c++ interface for the driver

Comment: std::chrono::high_resolution_clock and QueryPerformanceCounter give the same result both with a resolution of 0.1 microseconds. And both giving very varying results for each run!

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard doesn't say a whole lot about time. There are a few features inherited from C via the `<ctime>` header.

The function `clock` is the only way to get sub-second precision, but precision may be as low as one second (it is defined by the macro `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`). Also, it does not measure real time at all, but processor time.

The function `time` measures real time, but (usually) only to the nearest second.

To measure real time with subsecond precision, you need a nonstandard library.