# C++ Jittery game loop - how to make it as smooth as possible?

Tags: c++, math, timing, game-loop, jitter

This is my gameloop code:

```
        while (shouldUpdate)
        {
            timeSinceLastUpdate = 0;
            startTime = clock();

                while (timeAccumulator >= timeDelta)
                {
                    listener.handle();
                    em.update();
                    timeAccumulator -= timeDelta;
                    timeSinceLastUpdate += timeDelta;
                }

            rm.beginRender();
                _x->draw();
            rm.endRender();

            timeAccumulator += clock() - startTime;
        }
```

It runs almost perfectly, but it has some jitter to it, a few times a second instead of _x (a test entity that all it does in update is x++) moving 1 pixel to the right, it actually moves 2 pixels to the right and it's a noticeable lag/jitter effect. I'm guessing clock() isn't accurate enough. So what could I do to improve this game loop?

If it matters I use SDL and SDL_image.

**EDIT**: Nothing changed after doing something more accurate than clock. BUT, what I have figured out, is that it's all thanks to timeDelta. This is how timeDelta was defined when I made this post:

```
double timeDelta = 1000/60;
```

but when I defined it as something else while messing around...

```
double timeDelta = 16.666666;
```

I noticed for the first few seconds the game started, it was smooth as butter. But just a few seconds later, the game stuttered hugely and then went back to being smooth, and repeated itself like that. The more 6's (or anything after the . really) i added, the longer the game was initially smooth and the harder the lag hit when it did. It seems floating errors are attacking. So what can I do then?

EDIT2: I've tried so much stuff now it's not even funny... can someone help me with the math part of the loop? Since that's what's causing this...

EDIT3: I sent a test program to some people, some said it was perfectly smooth and others said it was jittery like how I described it. For anyone that would be willing to test it here it is(src): https://www.mediafire.com/?vfpy4phkdj97q9j

EDIT4: ***I changed the link to source code***.

Comment: Either go for `std::chrono` for C++ or check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521146/what-is-the-best-most-accurate-timer-in-c) for C for the most accurate timers.

Comment: Don't use `clock()` for a timer in something like a game.

Comment: timeDelta is causing the issue it seems

Comment: `timeDelta` should *not* be a constant. You could wait until it is greater than or equal to a certain value so that you get a framerate cap, but it should still be calculated per frame.

Comment: Not a solution, but you only need to call clock once in the loop. As it is you call it once at the end, and then immediately call it again at the start of the loop, when the value will be almost exactly the same. set startTime once before the loop starts, then set it again at the end of the loop with the value returned from clock()

Comment: I don't really know how to do the math of a game loop, I just copied some of that code from the Internet and edited it since there is literally no game loop examples in C++ I can find.

Comment: @Omega it isn't specific to C++, there are plenty of game loop examples in psuedo-code

Comment: ALSO you should give the source code, not an executable. People don't usually want to run random executables off mediafire. I'm not even running windows, so I can't test it without the source code either.

Comment: `1000/60` is integer division, and results in `16`.  If you want the best double, then use `1000.0/60`.  But better would be CoffeeandCode's suggestion of a frame rate cap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will almost certainly be because of the accuracy of `clock()`

Use either `std::chrono` or `SDL_GetTicks()` to measure time since epoch.

I would recommend using `std::chrono` just because I prefer C++ api's, here's an example:

```
int main(){
    using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using milliseconds = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;

    auto start = clock::now(), end = clock::now();
    uint64_t diff;


    while(running){
        diff = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        start = clock::now();     

        // do time difference related things

        end = clock::now();
    }
}
```

To only update after a specified delta, you'd do your loop like this:

```
int main(){
    auto start = clock::now(), end = clock::now();
    uint64_t diff = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();

    auto accum_start = clock::now();
    while(running){
        start = clock::now();
        diff = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();

        if(duration_cast<nanoseconds>(clock::now() - accum_start).count() >= 16666666){
            // do render updates every 60th of a second
            accum_start = clock::now();
        }

        end = clock::now();
    }
}
```

`start` and `end` will both be of the type `std::chrono::time_point<clock>` where `clock` was previously defined by us as `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

The difference between 2 `time_point`'s will be a `std::chrono::duration` which can be nanoseconds, milliseconds or any other unit you like. We cast it to milliseconds then get the `count()` to assign to our `uint64_t`. You could use some other integer type if you liked.

My `diff` is how you should be calculating your `timeDelta`. You should **not** be setting it as a constant. Even if you are certain it will be correct, you are wrong. Every frame will have a different delta, even if it is the smallest fraction of a second.

If you want to set a constant frame difference, use [SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval) to set vertical sync.

### EDIT

Just for you, I created [this example git repo.](https://github.com/RamblingMadMan/exampleGL) Notice in `main.cpp` where I multiply by `diff` to get the adjusted difference per frame. This adjustment (or, lack of), is where you are getting your jitteriness.

Comment: could you give me a hint...?

Comment: about timeaccum... well, i got your version of the loop to work and i made timeaccum work like this http://pastebin.com/62f3Vbmf but it still has that jitter, how SHOULD i be doing it

Comment: What is `em` that you're referencing?

Comment: Look, I'll add an example of how to manually update only after `timeDelta` so that you can do that if you like. But you should really only rely on your vsync for that behaviour.

Comment: one more thing, is there a way to do it without having every single number times dt?

Comment: Tried the second example, but there is something missing. diff is always near zero. Both methods burn the CPU to 100%.